# Who ruled India when the Abbasid ruler Harun al-Rashid was the Caliph of Baghdad?

Tags: india

Who ruled India when the 5th Abbasid ruler Harun Al-Rashid was the Caliph of Baghdad?

How many rulers were there in Indian subcontinent?

Which areas did they rule?

Comment: I understand it was exceedingly rare in history for one government to hold sway over the whole subcontinent. For most of its history it looked more like Europe, with dozens of bickering states (and perhaps even more if you look under the hood a bit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Harun Al-Rashid was the Caliph of Baghdad from 786 to 809 (according to Wikipedia). According to [this map of the Eastern Hemisphere in the year 800](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aEast-Hem_800ad.jpg), the Indian subcontinent was divided between the [Rashtrakutas on the Deccan plateau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashtrakuta_Dynasty), the [Palas in the Gangetic plain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pala_Empire), and the [Gurjara-Pratiharas in modern day Rajasthan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gurjara-Pratihara), with a major [Abbasid presence in the Indus valley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbasid_Caliphate) (modern day Pakistan). However, much of the subcontinent appears to have been ruled by large kingdoms at the time.